# Neo4J 2 different datatypes of a property of a node

Tags: neo4j

I am working on a project where I send latitude and longitude. I have about 100 records where it is stored as String and 100 records where it is double. How can I change all the data of this properties to double? Can I do this using a query?

e.g:

```
match n where has(n.`longitude`) return n
```

returns all the nodes which have longitude property. Can I set through a query the value 41.000 (double) for all the longitudes?

Or is there a method to change the datatype of the node and store it's initial value as double? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`toFloat`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-tofloat) function:

```
MATCH (N) WHERE EXISTS (N.longitude) AND 
                EXISTS (N.latitude)
          SET N.longitude = toFloat(N.longitude),
              N.latitude  = toFloat(N.latitude )
RETURN count(N)
```